# How do I resolve error C2059: syntax error : '__asm' in Visual C++ 2010 Express

Tags: c, assembly, visual-c++-2010-express

The file in which there is inline asm code is of the form xyz.c I'm using Visual C++ 2010 Express IDE. I get the error mentioned in the title. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

My code roughly looks like this.

```
#include "xyz.h"

/*
; Multi-line comments
;
*/

__asm{
    Assembly code
}
 /*
; Multi-line comments
;
*/
.
.
.

__asm{
    Assembly code
}
 /*
; Multi-line comments
;
*/

__asm{
    Assembly code
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to compile for x64?

Comment: I take that back. VS Express does not have the 64-bit compiler.

Comment: The VS Express line of compilers are limited, maybe it just doesn't support the `__asm` extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not put the asm code (or any other code) directly into the global scope. You have to put it inside a function.

```
void f()
{
    __asm {
        Some code
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unclear about where the function "f" will be called..Could you explain more in detail(probably with some sample skeleton code how I could do that?)?
Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: In C all code has to be inside functions. It doesn't matter if it is regular C code or asm code. The function `f()` can be called just like any other function.

Answer (score 0):

This example works for me :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Add(int x, int y){
    asm(
          "addl %1, %0"
          : "=r"(x)
          : "m"(y), "0"(x)
    );
return x;
}


int main ()
{
    int x,y;

    cout<<"Enter first number\n";
    cin>>x; //enter first number
    cout<<"Enter second number\n";
    cin>>y; //enter second number

    cout<<Add(x,y)<<endl;

return 0;
```

}

You can see the different syntax. But the asm{} or __asm__{} or whatever with {} does not work with minGW, only with visual studio apparently.